# Toggle two variable selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, toggle

I'm hitting a bit of a brick wall. I have two variables that I want to toggle at the same time. However, I seem unable to carry out this action without writing two lines of code.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
var $i,
    $e;

$i.toggle();
$e.toggle();
```

At the moment, the following will not work, but is it possible to write it more efficiently e.g:

```
$($i, $e).toggle();
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you expecting from `$(undefined, undefined)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$($i).add($e).toggle();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's done it. Do you know why you have to chain them like this?